# This linked list is not changed, in the main function does not work

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct listnode{
    int value;
    struct listnode *nextnode;
};
typedef struct listnode listnode;

void printlist(listnode *sptr){
    if(sptr == NULL){
        printf("No list!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The list is:");
        while(sptr != NULL){
            printf("%d-->",sptr->value);
            sptr = sptr->nextnode;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}
void insert(listnode *sptr, int item){
    listnode *newptr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    if(newptr != NULL){
        newptr->value = item;
        newptr->nextnode = sptr;
        sptr = newptr;
    }
    else{
        printf("No enough memory!\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    listnode *startptr = NULL;
    insert(startptr, 1);
    insert(startptr, 2);
    printlist(startptr);
}
```

The above are my code, it can compile, however, in the main function, when I call printlist, it does not `print(2->1->NULL)`, it prints the No list.I try to print the list inside the insert function, (after the line sptr = newptr), I use `printlist(sptr)`, and first time, it comes with `(1->NULL)`, and the second time, it comes out with `(2->NULL)`. I think the problem is each time, the `insert(&startptr, 1)`; the `startptr` does not change? Why?

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to the pointer, that is `listnode **sptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to a pointer, if you want that pointer itself to be updated to point to a new location.

```
void insert(listnode **sptr, int item){
    listnode *newptr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    if(newptr != NULL){
        newptr->value = item;
        newptr->nextnode = sptr;
        *sptr = newptr;
    }
    else{
        printf("No enough memory!\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    listnode *startptr = NULL;
    insert(&startptr, 1);
    insert(&startptr, 2);
    printlist(startptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be unaware that C is "call by value".

When you change the value of an argument inside a function, the caller's argument doesn't change.

This (in `insert()`):

```
sptr = newptr;
```

is pointless, it has no effect on the caller's `startptr` variable.

Consider *returning* the new head of the list.

By the way, consider a function like this:

```
void foo(int x)
{
  printf("in foo(), x=%d\n", x);
  x = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   foo(17);
}
```

In "your world", the above would try to make `17`, the caller's value for the argument `x`, equal to 0 by re-assigning it. But of course (?) re-assigning the value of a literal would make no sense, which is a good hint that it *doesn't* work like you think it does. Hm. Or perhaps that just adds more confusion, it's probably a bit subjective.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah ... just had a look but failed finding any. :( Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters are its local variables that are destroyed after exiting the function.

You can imagine the function `insert` and its call the following way

```
insert(startptr, 1);

void insert( /*listnode *sptr, int item */){
   listnode *sptr = startptr;
   int item = 1;
   //...
```

So any changes of the local variable `sptr` within the function do not influence on the original argument `startptr`. `startptr` will be unchanged after the call of the function.

You should either pass the header node by reference or return the new header node from the function.

So the function can be defined either like

```
void insert(listnode **sptr, int item){
    listnode *newptr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    if(newptr != NULL){
        newptr->value = item;
        newptr->nextnode = *sptr;
        *sptr = newptr;
    }
    else{
        printf("No enough memory!\n");
    }
}
```

and called like

```
insert(&startptr, 1);
```

Or the function can be defined like

```
listnode * insert(listnode *sptr, int item){
    listnode *newptr = malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    if(newptr != NULL){
        newptr->value = item;
        newptr->nextnode = sptr;
        sptr = newptr;
    }
    else{
        printf("No enough memory!\n");
    }

    return sptr;
}
```

and called like

```
startptr = insert(startptr, 1);
```

Comment: I don't like the first example, it's misleading as `startptr` is not accessible in `insert` function. I get what you mean, but for beginners it might be confusing.

Comment: @zoska I think he always can ask a question in a comment if there is something confusing.:)